# Type 1 group $\leftrightarrow$ every irreducible representation has a trace

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Is it equivalent for a separable, locally compact group:

- the group is type $1$,
- every unitary representation $\pi$ has a trace $\mathrm{tr} \; \pi: C_c^\infty(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?